# ReferenceError: callack is not defined in Node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

I am getting trouble while using callback as argument.

Here is the source.

```
authRequiredCall(socket1, 'media_file_add', function(userInfo, message) {
            saveMediaFile(message.project_id, message.path, function(err, result) {
                    console.log('send media_file_add response: ' + JSON.stringify(result))
                    socket1.emit('media_added', result);
            });
    });


function saveMediaFile(project_id, file_path, callback) {
        download(file_path, './uploads/')
            .on('close', function () {
                console.log('One file has been downloaded.');
                var filename = path.basename(file_path);

                putMediaToS3bucketAndSaveToDB(project_id, filename, callack);
            });
}


function putMediaToS3bucketAndSaveToDB(project_id, filename, callack) {

    ... 

    uploader.on('end', function() {
        var uploadedPath = s3.getPublicUrl(config.s3_config.BUCKET_NAME, newFilename, "");
        console.log("FILE UPLOADED", uploadedPath);
        fs.unlink("uploads/"+filename);
        uploadedPath = uploadedPath.replace('s3', 's3-us-west-2');
        console.log("PATH", uploadedPath);
        //Saving the file in the database
        addMediaFile(project_id, uploadedPath, callback);
    });
}


function putMediaToS3bucketAndSaveToDB(project_id, filename, callack) {

    ... 

    uploader.on('end', function() {
        var uploadedPath = s3.getPublicUrl(config.s3_config.BUCKET_NAME, newFilename, "");
        console.log("FILE UPLOADED", uploadedPath);
        fs.unlink("uploads/"+filename);
        uploadedPath = uploadedPath.replace('s3', 's3-us-west-2');
        console.log("PATH", uploadedPath);
        //Saving the file in the database
        addMediaFile(project_id, uploadedPath, callback);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to send callback as an argument to SaveMediaFile, but when I invoke putMediaToS3buketAndSaveToDB function with callback argument, it returns error message.

> ReferenceError: callack is not defined

I have no idea why callback is not defined while project_id and file_path has values.

Is there anyone to teach me the reason?

Help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a typo

```
function putMediaToS3bucketAndSaveToDB(project_id, filename, callack) 
                                                                 ^
```